# How to select direct layer in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-xd

I am creating a Halloween drawing and I am creating a pumpkin right now. I have a main layer with background and inside a pumpkin layer and inside a many pumpkin layers, now I want to select only that layer which I am pointing at. I know shortcut from Adobe Xd program which is: `CMD + Left Click` and it ignores parent/children dependiences. Can I do this in Illustrator too ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand. (no clue "that I am point at" indicates. I see no "pointing")

In your screenshot there is **only** one object selected.

**Only** the `<Compound Path>` is *selected*. This is noted by the outline around the circle on the right.

The red square indicators are there as a visual indicator of *where* the selection is located in the stacking order. The color squares *will* show for the hierarchy necessary to get to the selection.. but the colored squares do **not** indicate actual selection - they are merely visual cues.

Imagine if the layer stacking were all collapsed.... the red squares would tell you *which layer* the selection is on, then *which group* the selection is in, then where the *actual selection* is located.

---

If you are asking how to *only* select a single object like this, that is what the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) is for. The Direct Selection tool will select object while ignoring any groups or nested construction.

If you are seeking to be able to edit only that *group*, you can, by default, double-click with the **Selection Tool** (Black arrow) and enter **Isolation Mode** which will restrict editing to the group active in that mode. (Double-click again off of the artwork, or <kbd>ESC</kbd>, to exit Isolation Mode)

Comment: Yeah that isolation mode I was looking for and of course Direct Selection :) Many thanks